# How to get the first elements of COLLECT whithout limiting the global query?

Tags: neo4j

In a twitter like app, I would like to get only the 3 last USERS which has PUBLISH a tweet for particular HASHTAG (A,B,C,D,E)

```
START me=node(X), hashtag=node(A,B,C,D,E)
MATCH n-[USED_IN]->tweet<-[p:PUBLISH]-user-[FRIEND_OF]->me
WITH p.date? AS date,hashtag,user ORDER BY date DESC
WITH hashtag, COLLECT(user.name) AS users
RETURN hashtag._id, users;
```

This is the result I get with this query. This is good but if the friend list is big, I could have a very large array in the second column.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| hashtag   | users                         |
+-------------------------------------------+
| "paradis" | ["Alexandre","Paul"]          |
| "hello"   | ["Paul"]                      |
| "public"  | ["Alexandre"]                 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

If I add a LIMIT clause, at the end of the query, the entire result set is limited.

Because a user can have a very large number of friends, I do not want to get back all those USER, but only the last 2 or 3 which has published in those hashtags

Is the any solution with filter/reduce to get what I expect?

Running neo4j 1.8.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing sub-collection will be worked on,

meanwhile you can use this workaround: http://console.neo4j.org/r/f7lmtk

```
start n=node(*) 
where has(n.name) 
with collect(n.name) as names 
return reduce(a=[], x in names : a + filter(y in [x] : length(a)<2)) as two_names
```

`Reduce` is used to build up the result list in the aggregator
And `filter` is used instead of the conditional `case ... when ...` which is only available in 2.0

`filter(y in [x] : length(a)<2)` returns a list with the element when the condition is true and an empty list when the condition is false

adding that result to the accumulator with `reduce` builds up the list incrementally

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, the new **filter** syntax is:

filter(x IN a.array **WHERE** length(x)= 3)